# Django/Python additional parameter causes internal server error

Tags: python, django

For `class Notification` I have

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "eng_notification"
    ordering = ('-created_at',)

[...]     type = models.CharField(max_length=10,
choices=TYPE_NOTIFY_CHOICES.items(), verbose_name="Type of Notification",
default='SYS')

@classmethod
def notify(cls, msg_or_mid, target, sender=None, types=['SYS'], **kargs):
    params = result = {}
    try:
        if isinstance(msg_or_mid, Message):
            msg = msg_or_mid
        else:
            msg = Message.objects.get(mid=msg_or_mid)
    except Message.DoesNotExist:
        log.debug(u'A template %s não existe na base de dados!' % msg_or_mid)
    except Exception:
        log.debug(u"Mensagem nao enviada: %s" % msg_or_mid)
    else:
        for k in kargs:
            params[k] = u"%s" % kargs[k]
        for type in types:
            n = cls()
            n.msg = msg
            n.target = target
            if sender:
                n.sender = sender
            n.type = type
            n.status = 2
            n.params = str(params) if params else "{}"
            if type == 'EMAIL':
                result[type] = n.sendEmail()
            elif type == 'SMS':
                result[type] = n.sendSMS()
            else:
                result[type] = n.sendSYS()
    return result
```

that works if called as

```
Notification.notify(
    msg,
    employee_from_user(solicitante),
    chamado=self.chamado.cache_numero,
    previsao=DateUtils.date_to_str(self.previsao_fim)
)
```

but causes `internal server error` if called with an extra parameter, `'SYS'`:

```
Notification.notify(
    msg,
    employee_from_user(solicitante),
    chamado=self.chamado.cache_numero,
    previsao=DateUtils.date_to_str(self.previsao_fim),
    'SYS'
)
```

Since I am a newbie I am completely lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the Python version you're using, as well as the exact error message and the full traceback ? Else, any answer will be a wild guess at best.

Comment: bruno desthuilliers  thanks a lot: python2.7, the error message displayed on the browser is internal server error, I will get the full traceback and post it. Take care.

Comment: Anyway: you cannot pass a positional argument after a named one. Also your function expects `types` to be a list, so passing a single string will definitly not work as expected. TL;DR : you want  `.notify(..., types=["SYS"])`

Comment: bruno desthuilliers  thanks a lot again for your kind help; I changed as you instructed, it WORKED LIKE A CHARM!

Comment: Note that you don't have to add `ANSWERED` to the title - just accept Bojan's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I HAD accepted Bojan's answer, as much as I would like to accept bruno desthuilliers' (despite not being an answer but a comment). Too bad my status here didn't allow me to vote on my own question for I have < 15 as reputation...

Answer (score 0):

The `'SYS'` in `Notification.notify()` is a positional argument, which method notify doesn't accept. Either add `*args` (and move 'SYS' before named arguments)

```
def notify(cls, msg_or_mid, target, sender=None, types=['SYS'], *args, **kargs):
```

or add name

```
Notification.notify(
    msg,
    employee_from_user(solicitante),
    chamado=self.chamado.cache_numero,
    previsao=DateUtils.date_to_str(self.previsao_fim),
    something='SYS' # now it will be in kwargs
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bojan Kogoj for your most kind help, as much as bruno's!